# Transfer eth from one goerli account to another

Tags: blockchain, etherscan, testnets, goerli

So, I sent from one goerli testnet account to another: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xa1a6a53ef3b7e54b5dd58e1f6983b0ab06bf6a2301ba2155e869ce1a77347b9e

But the eth did not show up on the intended account.  Does that mean.... it is gone?

I have done this before with no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the balance in the destination address:

https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xa060f940290a038cccba02f4d71988ad569304c2

Probably you just needed to wait a bit until the sufficient amount of blocks have been confirmed in Goerli testnet and etherscan servers can catch the event.